# Why can const in a class be defined later?

Tags: php, class

For PHP const, this will display string (5) "hello"

```
<?php
const Y = "hello";
const X = Y;
var_dump(X);
```

This will print string (1) "Y" with a warning that you are using Y without defining it.

```
<?php
const X = Y;
const Y = "hoge";
var_dump(X);
```

This shows string (5) "hello" and seems to be able to see `A::Y` before definition.

Why can't you refer to the back const outside the class, but inside the class? At that time, what is being processed in what order?

```
<?php
class A {
    const X = A::Y;
    const Y = "hello";
}
var_dump(A::X);
```

Comment: In the first examples the code is just executed as a series of linear statements, which is what they are. Whereas a class is more of a _definition_ than a series of instructions with a defined order. I don't know for sure, but in the class situation I think maybe the value of the property `X` is not evaluated until you try to use it, and likewise `Y`. Therefore if you ask for X it says "ah ok, to get `X` have to evaluate `A::Y`. So for that, first I need to evaluate `Y`. So it evaluates `Y`, passes that to the `A::Y` expression, evaluates that and returns it. That sounds logical to me, anyway.

Comment: It can do that because Y is at least defined in the class, even though it wasn't necessarily evaluated. Whereas in your example which returns the warning, it cannot do it because you are asking it to immediately evaluate `X = Y`, but that's impossible because `Y` is not defined until later.

Comment: (Or, it could be that when you declare the class, it declares all the properties and variables, and then evaluates them at that time (rather than waiting for them to be called from outside the class). I don't know. Someone who knows PHP internals might be able to comment. But either way it can work in the class because everything is defined before it is evaluated. The order in which you write the properties does not matter.)